# How to re-enable sleep mode in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, sleep

Years ago I found a way to disable sleep mode in Windows 7 to prevent users from making their machines inaccessible. Now I need to re-enable it and have not found a way to restore it. Sleep is grayed out in the shutdown options and is no longer listed under any power plans.

- This is not a GUI setting in control panels. That's no longer available. It was probably a registry entry, a group policy, or via the command line with a tool like powercfg
- It is not fixed from options under Administrative Templates/System/Power Management/Sleep Settings
- Trying to force a timeout such as powercfg -x -standby-timeout-ac 10 fails
- This was done on each workstation, not through a domain GPO

Comment: Check HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power.

Comment: If "HibernatedEnabled" is 0, set it to 1.

Comment: This does indeed add Hibernate to the shutdown options, but the Sleep option above is still grayed out.

Answer (score -1):

1. Launch Local Group Policy Editor (gpedit.msc)
2. Navigate to Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Power Management > Sleep Settings.
3. Check if any policy is enabled or disabled. Change it back to not configured.

Comment: "It is not fixed from options under Administrative Templates/System/Power Management/Sleep Settings"

Comment: @Moab Did you try it? It is the only policy where sleep can be disabled...

Comment: Yes, I did try it. All of them were at default. So I set en/disable appropriately and restarted. However, the "Sleep" option still wasn't listed. Enabling hibernation with powercfg instantly restores "Hibernate" to the menu, even without a reboot.

Answer (score -1):

This thread may help you out:
https://www.sevenforums.com/performance-maintenance/153687-wont-sleep-not-typical-issue.html#post1322657